# How to display search results from different categories with PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am working on a Classifieds website, and I have a question about retrieving search results.

My goal is to display the number of classifieds in each category next to the category-names.

For instance:

- Red Cars ( 821 )
- Android Phones (291 )
- Notebook Computers ( 929 )

What is the ideal way of getting these counts from the MySql database tables?

Is it to write one query to every single table in the database? This would mean a lot of queries for one visitor, and perhaps cause performance issues?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I haven't created the MySql table yet, so feel free to recommend ideal structure if it plays a big role in the counting.

Comment: wait, do you have a separate table for every category?

Comment: Actually, haven't created the database yet :) I will update question

Comment: shall i write the whole site and make the coffee to?

Comment: yes please - milk and 1 thx

Comment: Dagon: Umm, sorry but Im just asking BEFORE I do something I regret; Isn't this site about asking for advice from other programmers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to have one query for this need.

Assuming you have a Categories table and a no of classifieds say products  you should be able to do something like this:

```
    Select C.Category, Count(P.Id) as ProductsCount 
From Categories C left join Products P on C.Id = P.Category_Id
Group by C.Category    
Order by C.Category
```

Comment: +1 - good, quick response, and the `LEFT JOIN` is a nice touch for counting categories with zero products.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple query with a count(*) and group by the category id/name.

```
SELECT Categories.name, count(*) as cnt
FROM Categories
    LEFT JOIN Classifieds
        ON Classifieds.CategoryID=Categories.ID
WHERE Classifieds.EndDate > NOW()
GROUP BY Categories.name
ORDER BY Categories.name
```

That would get you all category names along with a count of each name where the classified hasn't ended.